# sed substitution on multiple lines

Tags: xml, bash, sed, centos7

I need to substitute owl:Class in the following text with the LP number

`Input`

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="https://loinc.org/LP173100-1">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="https://loinc.org/LP410935-3"/>
        <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Counseling (LP)</rdfs:label>
        <skos:prefLabel rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Counseling</skos:prefLabel>
        <loinc:hasCode rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">LP173100-1</loinc:hasCode>
    </owl:Class>
```

so that the substituted output looks like the following

`Output`

```
<LP173100-1 rdf:about="https://loinc.org/LP173100-1">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="https://loinc.org/LP410935-3"/>
        <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Counseling (LP)</rdfs:label>
        <skos:prefLabel rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Counseling</skos:prefLabel>
        <loinc:hasCode rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">LP173100-1</loinc:hasCode>
    </LP173100-1>
```

I have used `s/\(owl:Class\)\(.*org\/\)\(LP.*\)"/\3\2\3/g` for the first line but I don't know how to apply it on the last line. Is there a more elegant solution? I have a huge file where I need to do such substitution.

I am using a Centos OS 7.7 Linux machine.

Comment: Are you trying to replace a tag name in an xml node with a string like `"LP173100-1"`? If so, you should know xml tag names can't have `"` around them. Maybe you mean replace with `LP173100-1`?

Comment: @JackFleeting Thanks for pointing it out. I made the change

Comment: Do you really want to use `sed` for this? Using an XML tool will probably be both easier and more robust.

Comment: @tripleee I am open to suggestions. I just happen to be new to XML and sed

Comment: Probably see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261561/please-stop-linking-to-the-zalgo-anti-cthulhu-regex-rant which mainly talks about HTML, but of course the same broad reasoning applies to any XML application or indeed any structured format.

Comment: In that case, Lesson 1: `sed` is not appropriate for XML.

Comment: Absolutely agree w/ @chepner: xml and regex are like oil and water. Use something like xidel or xmlstarlet.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `\n` symbol with a different one (such that is not located anywhere else inside the file) and then continue working as usual.

```
cat foo.txt | tr '\n' '\r' | sed -e 's/\(owl:Class\)\(.*org\/\)\(LP.*\)"/"\3"\2\3/g'  | tr '\r' '\n'
```

Comment: Some `sed` variants will have trouble with very long lines. And of course, lose the ugly [useless `cat`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Comment: The unbounded `.*` will consume as much of the string as it can. Downvoting as clearly untested.

Comment: Question was about multiple line sed substitution and the expression is taken from the original post.

Comment: But then that regex will no longer work correctly when everything is a single line. Changing it to `[^\r]*` would work if yowr `sed` supports the symbolic notation `\r`; but many do not. You could switch to Perl instead of `sed` for portability, but then Perl offers many far superior ways to solve the problem without regex.